# Unusual large size PDF for no obvious reason, why?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

This pdf document (with no media files except from a small logo) of four pages is just below 4 mb in size:

https://danskebank.dk/PDF/PRISER-VILKAAR-FAKTAARK/Investering/DB0300_ISD_I_DK.pdf

Since it makes absolutely no sense I opened it in Acrobat (pro), saved it as seperate pages and then merge them again. The result was 200 KB, much more in line with what I expected.

My question is now, what did the split/merge actually strip out of the file? At no point did I get a warning about losing any kind of functionality. And when asked Acrobat to compare the two files, it found no difference.

Comment: Fonts maybe? Or additional graphics? When saving a file some programs allow you to insert the fonts used and its possible that whatever exporter used has a generic set it always injects. Many compression or merging programs will strip unused parts of the file and they will be cut back out... only a guess hence a comment.

Comment: Have you tried using Adobe Acrobat's "Audit Space Usage" function?

Comment: PIgeonburger: Thanks. And Mokubai, yes, it was the fonts, 98,4% of the total size...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Adobe Acrobat's [Audit Space Usage](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/optimizing-pdfs-acrobat-pro.html#audit_the_space_usage_of_a_pdf_acrobat_pro) function, you can see exactly what in your PDF is taking up all the space.

The reason the file might be smaller after you manually join the pages together is because files inside the PDF (such as images or font files) were not compressed properly initially.